# How to permanently unhide the Users Library folder in Catalina

Tags: macos, catalina

I would like to permanently unhide the /Users/`<myname>`/Library folder so that it is always viewable in a new Finder window. Please note, I am NOT referring to the Option+Go menu method. MacOS version is 10.15.2

I have tried:

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library
killall Finder
```

This does not have the desired effect. I would prefer not to resort to:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's a visible pref for it, no need to dig in `defaults`

This is simplest if you use Icon or List view*

Open to your User's Home folder - `/users/[yourname]/` -  then either View Menu > Show View Options or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>J</kbd> 
Check the box for Show Library Folder.

[image]

*This is just because in Column view you're less certain exactly which folder you are affecting. The Show Library option only appears when you're in exactly the right folder.

Answer (score 10):

On the command line it's:

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library && xattr -d com.apple.FinderInfo  ~/Library
```

No need to kill *Finder.app*!

---

Both commands (`chflags ...` & `xattr ...`) remove a "hide flag" here. Especially the second command  - the first one is well known already - removes the extended attribute *com.apple.FinderInfo* of the user's Library folder with the content: `0000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` which - when applied like this - hides files and folders immediately.

In return you can hide files and folders by applying:

```
xattr -wx com.apple.FinderInfo "0000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" foo.bar
```

If the file or folder already has an extended attribute com.apple.FinderInfo (e.g. a single color tag) it will be overwritten.

Apparently you can combine tags/flags in com.apple.FinderInfo and:

```
xattr -wx com.apple.FinderInfo "0000000000000000400400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" foo.bar
```

will hide the file and apply a green tag.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what the 'xattr -d com.apple.FinderInfo  ~/Library' command is doing?

Comment: @codecowboy In the default config (invisible) the folder is hidden **and** has an extended attribute: com.apple.FinderInfo. To make it visible you have to remove the hidden flag as well as *com.apple.FinderInfo*.